# Use batch file to find a line in files in a folder, delete that line and save the file with the same name

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, findstr

Using a batch file I need to go through all pipe-delimited CSVs in a folder, find the line with dashes and pipes (will always be the second line in the files), delete that line and save the file with the same name in the same location.

The dashes/pipes line will vary in how many dashes are between pipes and will vary on how many pipes there are in the line, so the line can look like this:

```
------|-----------|---|----------------------|------
```

or it can look like this:

```
---------------|--------|-------------------|--|----------|-----|-------
```

Depends on the data in the file.

I'm just learning looping and findstr in batch files, but I have the following put together through reading and experimenting:

```
@echo off

set _outputfolder="D:\A Folder\A Sub Folder\Testing Folder"
echo.
echo %_outputfolder%

for %%F in (%_outputfolder%\*.csv) do (

    REM Sanity checks
    echo.
    echo path ^& file: "%%~F"
    echo.
    echo file: %%~nxF

    @findstr /r /b /c:"-*|" "%%~F"

    @findstr /r /b /c:"-*|" "%%~F" > "%_outputfolder%"\tmp.csv

    copy /y "%_outputfolder%"\tmp.csv "%%F"

)

@pause
```

The first `@findstr` correctly echoes the line with dashes in each file, but for each loop iteration for the second `@findstr` line I get this:

```
Access is denied.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

I'm not sure what part of my syntax is incorrect, though. I tried changing the end of the second `@findstr` line to try to output the file differently, but no matter what I've done so far I keep getting the "Access is denied..." message.

Comment: Use quotation like this: `set "_outputfolder=D:\A Folder\A Sub Folder\Testing Folder"`, so the quotes are no longer part of the variable value; you are actually doubling the quotation, which lets the path with spaces appear unquoted here: `> "%_outputfolder%"\tmp.csv`, which should actually read `> "%_outputfolder%\tmp.csv"`, by the way...

Comment: I answered you on [DosTips](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8638).  You are also missing a key switch.  You don't want to output the lines that match. You want to output the lines that do not match.

Comment: Thanks, Squashman. I got the quotes issue fixed (thanks, @aschipfl), but yes, you're correct. The matching line with the dashes and pipes is what is getting written to the file. I tried working with your nested for loop from the DosTips post, but I'm not seeing how to do that, as in that you're doing something with colons and such because you didn't know what exactly I was searching for at that time.

Comment: @marky, [my code on DosTips](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8638#p57235) isn't doing anything with colons nor are there nested FOR commands.  That is PenPen's code.

Comment: You should consider doing your sqlcmd differently to not output the dashes.  There are ways to work around that.  Plenty of answers here on StackOverFlow that address that.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just do something as crude as this?

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "dirSrc=D:\A Folder\A Sub Folder\Testing Folder"
CD /D "%dirSrc%" 2>Nul || Exit /B
For %%A In ("*.csv") Do Findstr "[^-|]" "%%A">"%%~nA.$csv$" && Del /A /F "%%A"
Ren "*.$csv$" "*.csv"
```

Comment: I like the use of the inverse character class.